# How to show this algorithm on positive semidefinite matrices converges to a global maximum determinant

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, recursive-algorithms, semidefinite-programming

I'm dealing with an algorithm which is supposed to converge to the maximum determinant of certain positive semidefinite matrices.

The problem is that we have such a matrix, and we vary certain entries within it. We have an algorithm that maximizes the determinant in each coordinate sequentially. Given a starting matrix $A_0$, this generates a sequence $\{A_i\}_{i=0}^\infty $of positive semidefinite matrices with increasing determinant which converges to something. I want to show that something is the maximum positive semidefinite completion.

The set of positive semidefinite matrices when varying these coordinates is compact and convex, and I've already shown our maximum is unique. But say our converges to a completion $A_\infty$ for which $\det(A_\infty) < \det(A_{max})$. How do I show this is a contradiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to fully answer your question without more information about the algorithm and the particular set of "certain" positive semidefinite matrices you are considering. In other words, what are the constraints on $A$ other than semidefiniteness? Still, there are several things that can be said.

First: your solution $A_\infty$ is positive definite, not just positive semidefinite; because if it were not, then your sequence could not have increasing determinant.

Second: both $f_1(A)=\det(A)^{1/n}$ and $f_2(A)=\log\det(A)$, are smooth, concave functions of the elements of $A$ on the open set of positive definite matrices. Therefore, the maximization of the determinant is a convex optimization problem, if the set you are considering is a convex set. Therefore, if the set of matrices under consideration is convex, we know a convergent algorithm must exist. Indeed, determinant maximization is a very common convex optimization paradigm. (Generally people talk about $f_2$ more than $f_1$, but in theory you could maximize either.)

It sounds like you're doing coordinate ascent. I do not believe that coordinate descent has been shown to converge globally for all functions, but I'll bet for the specific case of a smooth, strictly convex function on a convex set, there are some useful results in the literature.

EDIT: Based on the comments below, the you know a certain fraction of the values of $A$. This is just a positive semidefinite matrix completion problem. It's actually a well known problem in the convex optimization space. Search for "determinant maximization" and "positive definite matrix completion" online, and look in particular at work by Stephen Boyd, Lieven Vandenberghe, etc. Their MAXDET software is a bit out of date, though; I'd say SDPT3 is a good choice for code to solve maxdet problems of small to medium size. Coordinate descent seems awfully inefficient for this kind of problem, but I assume you've found a way to find descent directions cheaply.

Comment: Thank you for your very complete reply. I guess I should have been more clear, the function $f(A)=\log \det (A)$ is the function we are maximizing over. The set of matrices I am optimizing over is when taking a partially specified matrix $A$ we assume there is a positive semidefinite completion. Then we optimize over the set of valid postive semidefinite completions by doing a coordinate ascent through the coordinates of unspecified matrix entires. I've found some literature (Luenberger: Linear/nonlinear programming) but I found the proof given lacking, for the reason stated above.

Comment: Luenberger won't be a good source for you. See my edit for a start.

Comment: I'll have a look at those references when I can. Good to hear there might be a more efficient approach, I'm researching this topic for my masters thesis so it's still all quite new to me. Computational efficiency is fairly important.

Comment: You may want to take a look at my software [CVX](http://cvxr.com). It will make it easy for you to just code up some toy problems and see it in action. It won't be the most efficient way to go about it, though. SDPT3 has built-in support for determinant maximization that CVX doesn't take advantage of, which is why I recommended it first. For large scale problems a custom solver may be called for; I'm thinking a dual approach.

Comment: Yes we are utilizing an updating mechanism so that we can maximize the determinant per coordinate in a relatively cheap manner. But if you think another approach could still be faster I'm very interested what you think would be fruitful to investigate. What do you mean by a "dual approach"? I've seen references to the dual of a problem and "primal-dual interior-point methods". Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Yes. I think a study of semidefinite programming would be fruitful for you. Associated with every convex optimization problem is a dual---which is also a convex optimization problem. In this case, I believe the dual will be sparse, whereas the primal will not be, and this may make it easier to solve larger problems. The key is, once you have a solution to the dual, you can recover the solution to the original problem. I'm afraid this is not something you can learn in a comment thread though!